# If Blackbeard removes your power do you regain the ability to swim?

Tags: one-piece

When Blackbeard touches a devil fruit user, it is as if they don't have powers. Unlike the sea, when he drains your power, even physical property changes to your body are cancelled out.

The [Wikia on Yami Yami no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yami_Yami_no_Mi) talks about this:

> This was shown when Luffy's stretching powers were canceled on touch, unlike the effect of a body of water or seastone, both of which just inhibit a person from controlling their powers. It was shown earlier when Luffy was stuck underwater that his neck could still be stretched above the water's surface, and that Busoushoku Haki would simply nullify the defensive aspects of a Devil Fruit such as intangibility and the malleability of rubber.

The episode they are talking about is episode 447. In this episode, Blackbeard uses vortex to pull in Luffy and smashes Luffy into the ground. Crocodile notes that there was blood. This is strange since Luffy, being rubber, should be immune to the physical damage caused by being slammed into the ground.

Another use of the Yami Yami no Mi allowed Blackbeard to permanently remove a devil fruit user's power and give it to himself. When Whitebeard died his power was still active in Blackbeard, thus causing the fruit to not regrow. This is proof of the permanent transference of power.

In either of these cases, either the case where the devil fruit user has their power drained temporarily by touch, or permanently like in the case of whitebeard, would the drained user regain their ability to swim?

Comment: I don't know, but I think Yami Yami no Mi doesn't really remove other DF user, it's only negate the power of DF by touching the user. If You read more from your link it is stated that **The most unique and frightening advantage of the fruit is that the user also has the ability to _nullify_ the powers of other Devil Fruits by simply touching the user and draining them of their abilities.** even this might be true that BlackBeard can remove other DF user, but if only BlackBeard touch the user not permanently remove the power of other DF user.

Comment: And also this,  **In addition, while the ability to nullify Devil Fruit abilities is very powerful, _the user must actually touch and remain in contact with the victim for the effects to remain constant, meaning that if the victim is somehow separated from the user's physical touch they will quickly regain their Devil Fruit abilities._** BlackBeard can't remove the power of DF user if he doesn't touch the victim, that mean the user can't regain the ability to swim if BlackBeard not touch the victim.

Answer (score 2):

Doubtful. I think to completely rip off powers from another Devil Fruit user like Whitebeard, he probably needs to be dead or will die in the process. Think about it if that weren't the case, then Blackbeard would have extracted the Mera Mera no Mi's power from Ace when he initially captured him. The thing would've killed Ace and that wouldn't allow for a situation where Whitebeard went to war with the World Government.

Answer (score 0):

If the devil fruit was not reborn then Yami Yami no Mi does not just take powers, it takes the whole thing, like the person has actually ate another fruit. Hence, I surmise that yes, a person would be able to swim again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the point of such questions. Its clearly never been made clear the extent of BB's powers. (Logia intangibility, Removing other DF's powers etc. etc.) Unless Oda decided to make this a plot point somewhere down the line, I wouldn't really care how the DF mechanics work for the Yami Yami no Mi. But fans are really passionate about it So here's my answer. There is no real point in it.

It is shown quite clearly that BB needs to be touching the user to negate the DF powers (Whitebeard and Ace fights). So in order for a DF user to swim,

1. BB sits in a boat, holds one arm or touches the body of DF user. The boat has to follow the same exact path and speed of the swimmer and the instant BB loses the touch DF user drowns and BB can't save him. Unless the boat can just have 1 pirate on it, I'd rather just row.
2. BB himself can't swim being a DF user. He will lose strength and from what I know the Yami Yami no Mi power is not auto triggered.

Thus only plausible scenario is

3. That BB can maintain his DF fruit power even when he is submerged in water, and then a DF fruit user can carry him across water.

I think 3 is improbable since Crocodile did say that he has trained himself to turn into sand. Similarly BB needs to concentrate to hold his DF power and wouldn't be able to do so if submerged. Thus this power is imho inconsequential.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Blackbeard can remove the power of Devil Fruit permanently and the victim can't regain the ability to swim.

Just like stated [here](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yami_Yami_no_Mi)

> The most unique and frightening advantage of the fruit is that **the
>   user also has the ability to *nullify the powers of other Devil Fruits
>   by simply touching the user and draining them of their abilities*.**
>   All types of Devil Fruit, be it a Paramecia, Zoan or Logia, are
>   affected by this, though Logias are most affected as they can no
>   longer become intangible by transforming into their respective
>   element.  This nullification truly seems absolute, as though the Devil
>   Fruit users had never gained their powers at all.

And also this [part](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Yami_Yami_no_Mi#Weaknesses) stated that Blackbeard can nullify the power of other Devil Fruit users if he touch them.

> In addition, while the ability to nullify Devil Fruit abilities is
>   very powerful, 
>   **the user must actually touch and remain in contact with the victim for the effects to remain constant, meaning that *if the victim is
>   somehow separated from the user's physical touch they will quickly
>   regain their Devil Fruit abilities*.**

So, the victims can't regain their ability to swim if Blackbeard doesn't touch them to nullify their Devil Fruit power.

They can probably, swimming by carrying Blackbeard on their back.

Comment: `A person can lose their devil fruit and not die?` Just for clarification.

Comment: @Hikari lose their power by the power of Yami Yami no Mi, just like Michael stated in his question, Luffy lose his power because Blackbeard using the power of his DF and Luffy doesn't died and also I don't think there's someone that has lose the power of DF then died.

Comment: No that's not what I mean. I'm talking about like what blackbeard did to whitebeard. Can someone have their devil fruit absorbed completely. And not die? Because every time I've seen it happen so far. Someone has died.

Comment: @Hikari we don't know yet if someone can lose their ability completely or not. In Whitebeard case, his DF power was absorbed by Blackbeard by unknown method after his death, it's not revealed in anime or manga so far.

Comment: Ok that's what I was asking. I wonder how the hell that happened. Plus I know in the anime and manga it's been declared that Blackbeard's crew has been hunting df users and stealing their powers. So I'm assuming that method isn't strictly under blackbeard

Comment: @Hikari just wait until Blackbeard appeared in manga and anime again :D